# Room for a month in Vienna

Tags: accommodation, internet, vienna

The usual sites are for longer term rents in Austria - I need a room for a month. Obviusly, a hotel would be too expensive.

What site or social media group could help me finding a room for a month, possibly in a WG?

Comment: The usual suspect would be Airbnb. You may also look for “serviced apartments”.

Comment: And what is a WG?

Comment: Wohnunggemeinschaft, Vienna people should recognize that.

Comment: In Austria they call it Garconniere, sometimes.

Comment: Like a student corridor?

Comment: @jcaron WG is the word for a shared appartement in German(y)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to stay for a month in Vienna a vacation rental/Airbnb would be the most common choice.
Search for ["Ferienwohnung Wien"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=ferienwohnung%20wien) and you will find multiple websites offering accommodations (of which Airbnb usually isn't the cheapest)

A WG is a possible option with the website ["WG-Gesucht.de"](https://www.wg-gesucht.de/wg-zimmer-in-Wien.163.0.1.0.html) being a good choice for searching but simply searching for ["wg wien"](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=wg%20wien) on Google will give you the best results.

Nevertheless I think your chances are slim for a WG as most landlords want long-term tenants. You best chance would be to find somebody who sub-rents their room for some time.

Using social media groups for finding housing isn't a good option if you need to ask for those groups as you're obvious not *part* of those social groups.

*Good luck searching!*

Comment: In Hungary, there are facebook groups for some cities for room search and offer.

Comment: And yes, sub-rent is the word I looked for. Somebody would go on holiday and I could use that room while it is empty.